# Can I convert a Minecraft: Education Edition world to Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-education-edition

I made a world in Education Edition and would like to continue playing in Bedrock. I exported the world, but when I try and open it in Bedrock it says:
[image: Error message.]

*This level was saved from Minecraft: Education Edition. It cannot be loaded.*

Is there a way to load it?

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use an NBT editor, this is most certainly possible, if you know where to look.

## Prerequisites

- You have access to Minecraft: Bedrock Edition and Minecraft: Education Edition.
- You have an NBT editor that can edit MCBE and MCEE world files.

## Step One: Get the world file.

There are two methods you may take to access the world file. You can either find the folder for yourself, or you may use the Export World button in MCEE.

- ### Method A: Direct folder access

  Windows 10 devices can use the following file path to find their files. Users on a different OS, sorry, I am unable to provide a file path for you yet. If you have one, please comment below.

  ```
  C:\Users\ExpertCoder14\AppData\Roaming\Minecraft Education Edition\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
  ```

  Obviously replace `ExpertCoder14` above with your actual Windows username.

  [image: A file browser navigated to the location where Minecraft Education Edition world files are stored]
  (ignore that this one has `_UMCbackup`, that's just from past experimentation.)

  Unfortunately the names of the folders do not provide any indication of which world is which. The only way to find out is to enter it and open the `levelname.txt` file there.

  [image: A file browser navigated to the level name dot T X T file that stores the name of the world]
  Once you have found the folder that contains the world you wish to use, copy its entire world folder (not just `levelname.txt`) to somewhere you can easily access. I just put it on my Documents folder. Up to you.
- ### Method B: Export button

  You'll be able to save a `.mcworld` file to your computer by clicking the highlighted button in the image below.

  [image: A screenshot of Minecraft Education Edition showing the export button]

  You should be able to open this file directly with UMCE. If your NBT editor does not support `.mcworld` editing, you'll need to convert it to an actual folder by changing the filename extension from `.mcworld` to `.zip` and extract the files into another folder.

Whew! You've successfully retrieved the world file. Now for step 2...

## Step Two: Edit level NBT

Open your NBT editor. Go to the `level.dat` file of the world, and look for the Integer tag named `eduOffer`. Change it from `1` to `0`. The following image shows where to find the correct NBT tag in UMCE:

[image: A screenshot of Universal Minecraft Editor showing the location of the E D U offer tag.]

Ensure that you save the file and then close it! Otherwise your changes won't take effect.

Importantly, if you chose method B from step 1, ensure you've converted the world back to `.mcworld` format before continuing. This will involve creating a compressed folder and then renaming the extension to `.mcworld`.

## Step Three: Import the world

You'll need to follow a different step depending on which method you used in step 1.

- ### If you chose method A

  Move the edited world folder to the following Windows file path:

  ```
  C:\Users\ExpertCoder14\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
  ```
- ### If you chose method B

  Use the import button in Bedrock Edition to select your edited `.mcworld` file.

Answer (score 2):

ExpertCoder14 answer works with a few tweaks!
First: converting to .zip via renaming seems to break the files (the UMCE didn't want to open them anyway)
Instead what you can do is use 7zip, which can extract .mcworld directly

From there follow the instruction to change the tag, save.
You also cannot rezip it and convert it the other way, it also didn't work (my win10 minecraft wouldn't load it)

Instead you have to copy the folder into the win10 savegame folder on your computer (the instructions for this are also in the answer, just follow those)

Anyway, thanks a lot for this, it's going to be very cool for school kids that have normal minecraft at home!

Edit: for those who don't want to bother with 7zip, there is a minecraft editor that can open the EDU .mcworld directly, and then save them back, so you're just left with tag editing to do:
[MCC Tool Chest PE](http://www.mcctoolchest.com/Download)

Comment: I thought UMCE *does* work to open `.mcworld` though, you just need to push "Open File" instead of "Open Folder."

Comment: Might have been my world, but it didn't work when I tried either options *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

Sadly not. [Education Edition is functionally different from the rest of the game](https://minecrafteducation.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001434527-Features-of-Minecraft-Education-Edition-); objects such as specialty blocks, the Code Builder function, and NPCs are unique to EE and thus mean it cannot be ported to any other version.

Comment: Thanks for that one; I just wondered though, as the world contains no Education Edition-specific items?

Answer (score 0):

EE is 1.12.6, and BE is a different version. So you can't export it.