# Is there ANY way to make it so that a MCEE .mcworld file can be played on MCBE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-education-edition

I tried pretty much everything I know (which isnt a lot). Like just straight up importing, literally shoving it into the minecraft world files, and just kept changing a copy of the world to like .zip, .dir, and others. The world from MCEE is just a vanilla world and theres no mcee specific blocks since we don't use cheats.

Comment: You'll need an NBT editor like Universal Minecraft Editor to do this. If you have one, follow the instructions on [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/382472/250180).

Answer (score 0):

If a regular import of the mccworld file failed, that probably means your only option would be to attempt to convert with software such mcc tool chest or universal minecraft editor.

Comment: Wdym if the "regular import" failed? How would you do that in the first place?

Comment: On windows 10 you only need double-click the .mcworld file and win10 edition will launch and attempt to import the map.

Comment: how do u turn the edu into bedrock tho

Comment: It's an .mcworld file. Double clicking it would cause win10 to attempt to import it no matter what. That's what I meant by regular import. If that failed, the only other option would be a level editor. Education edition is based on bedrock (though has differences), so it may or may not succeed.